# Can i add other shapes than ellipse2D rectangle2D to "Shape" in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, geometry, shapes, graphics2d

I have an Arraylist that saves all shapes.

```
ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();
```

The ArrayList is of type `Shape` and hence has ellipse, rectangle, line, point. But now I want to draw a triangle and save it into that same ArrayList.

Is it possible to do this? I mean can I add other shapes to that `Shape`, other than `Ellipse2D`, `Rectangle2D`, etc?

**EDITED**

So this is what i use to draw a rectangle for e.g :

```
private Rectangle2D.Float drawRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            // Get the top left hand corner for the shape
            // Math.min returns the points closest to 0

            int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
            int y = Math.min(y1, y2);

            // Gets the difference between the coordinates and

            int width = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
            int height = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

            return new Rectangle2D.Float(x, y, width, height);
        }
```

So to draw my triangle i will have this?

`public class triangle implements Shape{`

Then i pass the parameters to draw the triangle here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Playing With Shapes](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/playing-with-shapes/) for some interesting ideas.

It shows you how to create a Triangle using the Polygon class:

```
Polygon triangle = new Polygon();
triangle.addPoint(0, 0);
triangle.addPoint(15, 30);
triangle.addPoint(30, 0);
shapes.add( triangle );
```

It also shows how to make more complex shapes like stars and hexagons using a utility class provided in the link.

Comment: Thank you. But will i be able to store this to my arraylist<Shape>?

Comment: Can you please help me out? Can I add triangle to that <Shape>?

Comment: @Lana, I don't understand the question. Did you try adding the triangle to your Shape ArrayList?

Comment: I want to know how i can add a triangle to "Shape" interface. "Shape" is normally used for Ellipse2D, Rectangle2D etc and does not have triangle in it. So how can i draw my triangle and add it to that "Shape" interface.

Comment: You didn't answer my question. Did you try to add the "triangle" to your "shapes" ArrayList? Polygon does implement the  Shape interface (did you read the API?). You just add the triangle to your ArrayList. I updated the code.

Comment: Yes Thank you i did read the API and polygon is in there. But what if i want to draw a shape that does not have a class in Shape that allows me to do this. Can i use this:  `public class Triangle implements shape{ //pass parameters to draw the triangle}` ?

Comment: @lana, There are 10 methods in the Shape interface. I have know idea how to implement those methods. That is why I suggeste you use the Polygon class. You could have "Triangle extends Polygon" and then pass 3 points to the triangle class. The triangle class would then just invoke the addPoint(...) method for all three points as I have demonstrated above.

Comment: What if i have to draw a diamond shape? what should i use then?

Comment: @Lana A `Polygon` can have "n" sides. In the case of a diamond you need to provide 4 points to the Polygon. If you want an Octagon you provide 8 points. You can be as creative as you need to be. So effectively any straight lined Shape can be provided by a Polygon (even a Rectangle), you just need to manage the points. Did you look at the link I provided you? It shows other ways to create some fancy shapes.

Comment: Can i use the rectangle class to draw a diamond? Since both takes 4 points?

Comment: Ok. So i can use polygon to create a diamond too. I can also use a rectangle since a rectangle takes 4 points too?

Comment: @Lana, A Point is an (x, y) co-ordinate. A Rectangle does not take 4 Points, it takes 4 parameters.

Comment: Ok. And if i want to draw an arrowline? what can i use?

Comment: @Lana, you can use a `GeneralPath`. Using the `lineTo(...)` and `moveTo(...)` methods you can combine multiple lines into one Shape.

Answer (score 1):

`Shape` is an interface. Therefore you can add every class implementing this interface to your `ArrayList`. from the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) you can add all of those from the java APIs:

> Arc2D, Arc2D.Double, Arc2D.Float, Area, BasicTextUI.BasicCaret,
>   CubicCurve2D, CubicCurve2D.Double, CubicCurve2D.Float, DefaultCaret,
>   Ellipse2D, Ellipse2D.Double, Ellipse2D.Float, GeneralPath, Line2D,
>   Line2D.Double, Line2D.Float, Path2D, Path2D.Double, Path2D.Float,
>   Polygon, QuadCurve2D, QuadCurve2D.Double, QuadCurve2D.Float,
>   Rectangle, Rectangle2D, Rectangle2D.Double, Rectangle2D.Float,
>   RectangularShape, RoundRectangle2D, RoundRectangle2D.Double,
>   RoundRectangle2D.Float

If you create a class **implementing** the interface `Shape`, you will also be able to add your object to your `ArrayList`.

Comment: Can you please see the above edited post?  Is this the way i should proceed to draw my triangle and make it saved to shape?